# How can I run Test projects with Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I'm currently running Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition and one of the items they cut out for that edition is the unit testing capability. As a result, when I open up example projects like the MVC commerce test, one of the projects just won't load since it doesn't know to open that type of project.

I know I can just exclude or remove the project and I am aware of TestDriven.NET, but is there a plugin for VS2008 Standard which will do the unit tests that come with VS2008 Pro? Will TestDriven.NET do this or are the tests different enough from NUnit testing that this won't work?

**UPDATE:** To clarify, I'm curious if there are any programs or plugins out there that can run Test projects *within Visual Studio 2008*. TestDriven.NET cannot load or run or allow VS2008 to open Test projects and Gallio does not run within the VS2008 IDE (although I appreciate the suggestions greatly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/) as explained best in [this blog post](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/09/26/gallio-the-framework-agnostic-test-runner-for-net/) by Richard Dingwall, and for Visual Studio support, use [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) to runs it.

There's some information available in [this Google Groups post](http://groups.google.com/group/gallio-dev/browse_thread/thread/8c880aa0a963244d) as well.

---

From Gallio's website:

> At present Gallio can **run tests from** MbUnit versions 2 and 3, **MSTest**, NBehave, NUnit, xUnit.Net, and csUnit.  Gallio provides tool support and **integration with** CCNet, MSBuild, NAnt, NCover, Pex, Powershell, Resharper, **TestDriven.Net**, TypeMock, and Visual Studio Team System.

Answer (score 2):

TestDriven.NET can run NUnit, xUnit.NET and MSTest. It's not free, though, but well worth it. From http://www.testdriven.net/overview.aspx:

> Supports multiple unit testing frameworks including NUnit, MbUnit and MS Team System.

Comment: Was TestDriven.NET ever free? Or did I imagine that?